# h:graphicImage does not display image in JSF

Tags: jsf, graphicimage

I have this in my class and I am trying to access it on my web page.

```
public String carImageURL = "/resources/images/sample_car.jpg";
```

This is the code I use in my web page that does not work.

```
<h:graphicImage value="#{carClass.carImageURL}"></h:graphicImage >
```

When I run the page there is no picture of the car in it.

Comment: Try without `/resources`

Comment: It did not work. The image is still not there.

Comment: Where do you have placed images?

Comment: inside the webapp/resources/images folder

Comment: try without the first `/` > `public String carImageURL = "resources/images/sample_car.jpg";`

Comment: There is still no image.

Comment: Inspect `img` object created by `h:graphicImage` and check what `src` value is.

Comment: There is no broken symbol/picture on the web page that says that it is not displaying. I tried right click inspect element and it gives me the same code that I have. The value for the img is there too.

Comment: I think that your problem is in your bean, so try to put the link of your image directly on the attribut in the <h:graphicimage> tag, if it works fine post your bean

Comment: *"I tried right click inspect element and it gives me the same code that I have"* you mean to say that you see JSF source code instead of its generated HTML output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the carImageURL attribute to private scope and write a getter method for it. Also write a slash at the beginning of the image path:

```
private String carImageURL = "/resources/images/sample_car.jpg";

public String getCarImageURL() {
    return carImageURL;
}
```